# Access denied when trying to install Linux Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, restricted-access

Following this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/windows-ubuntu-hyperv-containers#1-overview

In step 6 I try to run:

```
.\dockerd.exe -D --data-root C:\lcow
```

Then I get:

```
failed to load listeners: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied.
```

I am running it in administrator command prompt.

Comment: Hello. This error seems like it's related to the running of Docker on Windows - before any Ubuntu containers are even started. If this is the case, I believe [su] would be a better place to ask.